# Hadronic Calorimeters

Tags: particle-physics, particle-detectors

From the this reference, **https://indico.in2p3.fr/event/1873/contributions/21752/attachments/17734/21715/delphes.pdf**, it is stated that hadronic calorimeters are made up of heavy materials.

Is it necessary for hadronic calorimeters to be made up of heavy materials like iron or copper? If it is, why ?

Comment: Have you read this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorimeter_(particle_physics) . The bigger nuclei offer more protons and neutrons for a hadron hadron interaction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of a particle calorimeter, like the purpose of the calorimeters used by chemists, is to collect and measure all of the energy in an interaction. Hard radiation does not stop instantly in matter, but makes a cone of secondary radiation. Your particle calorimeter must be large enough to contain the overwhelming majority of this cone.

The major mechanism for energy loss in matter is the creation of electron-ion pairs. More mass generally means more electrons, and therefore a smaller volume of detector.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation rob.